# __init__ is not found on python class when using in jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, jupyter-notebook

I have this code as a class in my InputData.py file

```
class InputData:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.input_file_name = file_name
        print(self.input_file_name)
```

and I am trying to use it my jupyter notebook (both notebook and py files are on the same folder)

```
from  InputData import InputData
input_data=InputData('input file')
print(input_data.input_file_name)
```

in one cell.

When I ran this code, I am getting this error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-4288fe35f228> in <module>
      1 from  InputData import InputData
----> 2 input_data=InputData('input file')
      3 print(input_data.input_file_name)

TypeError: InputData() takes no arguments
```

Why does It say that InputData class has no argument when apparently, it has?

if I change the code to this:

```
from  InputData import InputData
input_data=InputData()
print(input_data.input_file_name)
```

I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-e11cc558c77a> in <module>
      1 from  InputData import InputData
      2 input_data=InputData()
----> 3 print(input_data.input_file_name)

AttributeError: 'InputData' object has no attribute 'input_file_name'
```

Apparently, the `__init__` is not seen and called. What is the problem?

## Edit 1

Based on comments I noted that the Jupyter notebook can not see the changes that I made to my class. How can I force Jupyter to see my changes?

Comment: Well, the `InputData` that you and Jupyter are referring to are different. I bet if you modified your `class InputData` to have: `def __init__(self, file_name, foo):` you would still see: `TypeError: InputData() takes no arguments`.

Comment: @quamrana yes I changed the class after I used it in jupyter. I think the changes that I made to class is not seen my Jupyter. How can I refresh Jupyter to see the changes?

Comment: it is bad practice to name your file the exact same name and case you are giving your object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a cell at the beginning of your notebook with the following commands and run it:

```py
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Now, you can change your code and rerun it in your notebook without restarting the kernel.